# R Highcharter Errorbar Series Position Dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2, highcharts, data-visualization, r-highcharter

I can't manage to get the error bars to overlay properly on my grouped column plot. In ggplot I would use position = position_dodge(), but I haven't been able to find something similar in the errorbar documentation for highcharts.

[image: see screenshot of what I have now]

Here's a MWE:

```
df <- data.frame(Gender = c("Male", "Male", "Female", "Female"),
                 ShareType = rep(c("Long", "Short"),2),
                 InvestedPerAccount = c(10,9,7,8),
                 lower = c(8,7,6,7),
                 upper = c(11.5,10,9,8.8))



highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(df, "column",hcaes(x = ShareType, y = InvestedPerAccount, group = Gender),
                tooltip = list(enabled = TRUE,pointFormat = '${point.y}')) %>%
  hc_add_series(df, 'errorbar', hcaes(x = ShareType, low = lower, high = upper, group = Gender, grouping = FALSE)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$ShareType, title = list(text = "Share Type")) %>% 
  hc_colors(c("pink","lightblue"))
```

Comment: Seems to be an open issue on github: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be use `id` parameter in the first group of series and then use `linkedTo` in the errorbar series. Due the `"errobar"` type series is linked to the previous one by default.

```r
example_dat <- tibble(Type = c("Human", "High-Elf", "Orc"), 
       key = c("World1", "World2", "World3")) %>% 
  expand.grid() %>% 
  mutate(mean = runif(9, 5, 7)) %>% 
  mutate(sd = runif(9, 0, 2)) 


hchart(
  example_dat, 
  "column",
  hcaes(x = key, y = mean, group = Type),
  id = c("a", "b", "c")
  ) %>%
  
  hc_add_series(
    example_dat,
    "errorbar", 
    hcaes(y = mean, x = key, low = mean - sd, high = mean + sd, group = Type),
    linkedTo = c("a", "b", "c"),
    enableMouseTracking = TRUE,
    showInLegend = FALSE
    ) %>% 
  
  hc_plotOptions(
    errorbar = list(
      color = "black", 
      # whiskerLength = 1,
      stemWidth = 1
    ) 
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's the way it's suppose to work, but maybe it's a workaround until you find *the* function.

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(df, "column",hcaes(x = ShareType, y = InvestedPerAccount, group = Gender),
                tooltip = list(enabled = TRUE,pointFormat = '${point.y}')) %>%
  hc_add_series(df, "errorbar", stemWidth = 1,  whiskerLength = 10, grouping = FALSE,
                centerInCategory = TRUE, groupPadding = .68,
                hcaes(x = ShareType, low = lower, high = upper, group = Gender)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$ShareType, title = list(text = "Share Type")) %>% 
  hc_colors(c("pink","lightblue"))
```

Answer (score 1):

@tamtam's answer works, but you need to set `groupPadding` to a strange, constant value, in this case 0.68.

**The real answer** is simple - errorbar series is, by default, connected to the previous series. So the order of your series should be defined like this:

`1. column 2. errorbar 3. column 4. errorbar`

Demo showing a correct order: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rmhw6f9y/

but the R wrapper adds them in this order:

`1. column 2. column 3. errorbar 4. errorbar`

Demo showing wrong order: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bw0p68f3/

---

Because the 4. errorbar is not connected to column (3. is not a column series), the error bars are grouped incorrectly.

**The solution** for this is simple - you need to connect 3. with 1. and 4. with 2. For that, you can use **column.id** and **errorbar.linkedTo** properties:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.id
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.errorbar.linkedTo

I don't know how we can add them to the chart's options (hc_add_series), but I know how to update series with JavaScript:

```
hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function () {
    this.series[0].update({
      id: 'firstColumnSeries'
    }, false);
    this.series[1].update({
      id: 'secondColumnSeries'
    }, false);
    this.series[2].update({
      linkedTo: 'secondColumnSeries'
    }, false);
    this.series[3].update({
      linkedTo: 'firstColumnSeries'
    });
  }"))) %>%
```

---

**This is the whole code:**

```
library('highcharter')

df <- data.frame(Gender = c("Male", "Male", "Female", "Female"),
                 ShareType = rep(c("Long", "Short"),2),
                 InvestedPerAccount = c(10,9,7,8),
                 lower = c(8,7,6,7),
                 upper = c(11.5,10,9,8.8))


highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function () {
    this.series[0].update({
      id: 'firstColumnSeries'
    }, false);
    this.series[1].update({
      id: 'secondColumnSeries'
    }, false);
    this.series[2].update({
      linkedTo: 'secondColumnSeries'
    }, false);
    this.series[3].update({
      linkedTo: 'firstColumnSeries'
    });
  }"))) %>%
  hc_add_series(df, "column",hcaes(x = ShareType, y = InvestedPerAccount, group = Gender),
                tooltip = list(enabled = TRUE,pointFormat = '${point.y}')) %>%
  hc_add_series(df, 'errorbar', hcaes(x = ShareType, low = lower, high = upper, group = Gender, grouping = FALSE)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$ShareType, title = list(text = "Share Type")) %>% 
  hc_colors(c("pink","lightblue"))
```

ps. you might want to swap `secondColumnSeries` with `firstColumnSeries` depending on which side you want to place your errorbar.